Show multiple screenshots on Redmi Note 10
I use this code to open camera and get uri after take image. It only not work on Redmi Note 10 (OS 11). it just shows the continuous screenshot. I guess the app is closed when I use intent to open camera
     private fun openCamera() {
        val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        val folderCache = File(cacheDir, "images")
        if (!folderCache.exists()) {
            folderCache.mkdirs()
        }

        try {
            // Tạo file tạm thời để lưu ảnh
            mPhotoFile = File.createTempFile(
                System.currentTimeMillis().toString(),
                ".png",
                folderCache
            )

            // Tạo Uri từ file với FileProvider
            mUri = mPhotoFile?.let { file ->
                FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider",
                    file
                )
            }

            // Kiểm tra mUri có null không, sau đó gọi mTakePhoto
            mUri?.let { uri ->
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)

                // Cấp quyền ghi tạm thời cho ứng dụng máy ảnh
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                takePictureIntentLauncher.launch(takePictureIntent)
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error creating file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

whyyyy and how to fix this please
